# Cache_hits very low after Mariadb migration

Tags: performance, mariadb

After mariadb 5.5 migration from percona we have a problem with our new db engine:

We have changed from percona mysql server 5.5 to mariadb but performace is not as good as we thought.
This graph is from a day in mariadb. You can see the low performace in terms of cache_hits
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAApV.png

We have others servers with percona mysql server 5.5. The graph below is from one of them:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BnjT.png

We dont know how there is only 46% of query cache efficiency.
With percona mysql server was near 90%.

This is my.conf from mariadb server

```
#
# * Fine Tuning
#

bulk_insert_buffer_size = 16M

concurrent_insert       = 2
connect_timeout         = 5

interactive_timeout     = 14400
join_buffer_size        = 1G
key_buffer              = 256M
key_buffer_size         = 256M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
max_connections         = 200

myisam_recover          = BACKUP
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 500M

open_files_limit        = 20000
table_open_cache        = 5000
table_definition_cache  = 3000

query_cache_limit       = 16M
query_cache_size        = 1G
query_cache_min_res_unit = 4K

read_buffer_size        = 8M
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 4M

sort_buffer_size        = 512K

aria-pagecache-buffer-size = 256M
key-cache-segments      = 8

thread_cache_size       = 128
thread_concurrency      = 8
thread_stack            = 192K

tmp_table_size          = 2G
max_heap_table_size     = 2G
wait_timeout            = 14400
```

---

mysqltuner:

```
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +Aria +BLACKHOLE +CSV +FEDERATED +InnoDB +MRG_MYISAM +SPHINX 
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 8M (Tables: 10)
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 872M (Tables: 146)
[--] Data in PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA tables: 0B (Tables: 17)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 11

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 1d 20h 47m 59s (40M q [248.063 qps], 2M conn, TX: 87B, RX: 3B)
[--] Reads / Writes: 97% / 3%
[--] Total buffers: 2.9G global + 1.0G per thread (200 max threads)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 204.3G (651% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 1% (529K/40M)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 11% (23/200)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 128.0M/92.7M
[OK] Key buffer hit rate: 100.0% (61B cached / 44K reads)
[OK] Query cache efficiency: 45.3% (28M cached / 62M selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (111 temp sorts / 1M sorts)
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 48% (1M on disk / 2M total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (23 created / 2M connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 68% (370 open / 541 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 2% (517/20K)
[!!] Table locks acquired immediately: 93%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 256.0M/8.4M
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0
```

Any help will be welcome.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Cache hits are not a good indicator of performance.  Do you have other metrics like server load or mysql cpu usage?  It would also be helpful to have either application side monitoring of the query execution times or samples of representative queries.  What storage engine are you primarily using?

Comment: low cache_hits increases CPU load in every server, always!
In both servers there is myisam as db engine.There are buffers too. You can see the conf attach in my post.

Comment: There are some general things you can do to improve performance.  Some of your buffer sizes look way off (specifically read_buffer_size and join_buffer_size).  http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com has good articles on setting them appropriately.  Other things to look at are the temp tables created on disk and slow queries.  I would also try using InnoDB especially since it looks like there is some write contention.  It can also be generally better since it tries to keep data in memory when possible.  Since every situation is different, you'll need to test different settings on your system.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the exact problem when migrating from MySQL to MariaDB, our query cache hitrate was reduced to 45 %.

I have spent hours debugging this issue but it turns out that there is nothing wrong with the query cache at all. The problem is how MySQL, Percona and MariaDB report the total amount of queries. The com_select status variable includes the Qcache_hits at MariaDB, while Percona and MySQL exclude these hits.

This is reported as a bug on https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-7216

When doing the the calculation for the cache hitrate MySQLTuner is calculating the total amount of queries twice, resulting in half the value (45 % instead of 90 %).

You probably have solved this issue in another way yet, but as this question turns up in Google I answer it here for other to find as well.